The cards are going up
I have some product cards. When you add 5 cards, they line up in a row, and when you add the sixth, they begin to rise one at a time. I've looked through all the code, but I can't figure out what my problem is. I'm asking for your help.ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ


.product-card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nft {
  user-select: none;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
  background-color: #282c34;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(40, 44, 52, 1) 0%, rgba(17, 0, 32, .5) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 20px 5px #00000088;
  border-radius: .7rem;
  backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s all;
  .wrapper li {
    margin: 10px 5px;
  }
  hr {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #88888855;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  ins {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .main {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: #c572e6;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    .tokenImage {
      border-radius: .5rem;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 250px;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    .description {
      min-height: 100px;
      max-height: 100px;
      margin: .5rem 0;
      color: #a89ec9;
    }
    .creator {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: .2rem;
      margin-bottom: -.3rem;
      ins {
        color: #a89ec9;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
        padding: .3rem;
        margin: 0;
        margin-right: .5rem;
        border-radius: 100%;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #000000aa;
        img {
          border-radius: 100%;
          border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
          width: 2rem;
          height: 2rem;
          object-fit: cover;
          margin: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
   ::before {
    position: fixed;
    content: "";
    box-shadow: 0 0 100px 40px #ffffff08;
    top: -10%;
    left: -100%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    height: 60rem;
    transition: .7s all;
  }
  &:hover {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff44;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 50px 10px #000000aa;
    transform: scale(1.015);
    filter: brightness(1.3);
     ::before {
      filter: brightness(.5);
      top: -100%;
      left: 200%;
    }
  }
}

.bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  h1 {
    font-size: 20rem;
    filter: opacity(0.5);
  }
}
 <div class="product-card-container">
            <div class="nft">
                    <div class='main'>
                      <img class='tokenImage' src="${productData.image}" alt="NFT" />
                      <h2 class="name-prod">${productData.name}</h2>
                      <div class='tokenInfo'>
                        <div class="price">
                          <p>${productData.price} руб</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="unit">
                         <button class="less">-</button>
                         <p class="unit-txt">${productData.quantity}</p>
                         <button class="more">+</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
             <div class="product-card-container">
            <div class="nft">
                    <div class='main'>
                      <img class='tokenImage' src="${productData.image}" alt="NFT" />
                      <h2 class="name-prod">${productData.name}</h2>
                      <div class='tokenInfo'>
                        <div class="price">
                          <p>${productData.price} руб</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="unit">
                         <button class="less">-</button>
                         <p class="unit-txt">${productData.quantity}</p>
                         <button class="more">+</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
             <div class="product-card-container">
            <div class="nft">
                    <div class='main'>
                      <img class='tokenImage' src="${productData.image}" alt="NFT" />
                      <h2 class="name-prod">${productData.name}</h2>
                      <div class='tokenInfo'>
                        <div class="price">
                          <p>${productData.price} руб</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="unit">
                         <button class="less">-</button>
                         <p class="unit-txt">${productData.quantity}</p>
                         <button class="more">+</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
             <div class="product-card-container">
            <div class="nft">
                    <div class='main'>
                      <img class='tokenImage' src="${productData.image}" alt="NFT" />
                      <h2 class="name-prod">${productData.name}</h2>
                      <div class='tokenInfo'>
                        <div class="price">
                          <p>${productData.price} руб</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="unit">
                         <button class="less">-</button>
                         <p class="unit-txt">${productData.quantity}</p>
                         <button class="more">+</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
             <div class="product-card-container">
            <div class="nft">
                    <div class='main'>
                      <img class='tokenImage' src="${productData.image}" alt="NFT" />
                      <h2 class="name-prod">${productData.name}</h2>
                      <div class='tokenInfo'>
                        <div class="price">
                          <p>${productData.price} руб</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="unit">
                         <button class="less">-</button>
                         <p class="unit-txt">${productData.quantity}</p>
                         <button class="more">+</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
             <div class="product-card-container">
            <div class="nft">
                    <div class='main'>
                      <img class='tokenImage' src="${productData.image}" alt="NFT" />
                      <h2 class="name-prod">${productData.name}</h2>
                      <div class='tokenInfo'>
                        <div class="price">
                          <p>${productData.price} руб</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="unit">
                         <button class="less">-</button>
                         <p class="unit-txt">${productData.quantity}</p>
                         <button class="more">+</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
             <div class="product-card-container">
            <div class="nft">
                    <div class='main'>
                      <img class='tokenImage' src="${productData.image}" alt="NFT" />
                      <h2 class="name-prod">${productData.name}</h2>
                      <div class='tokenInfo'>
                        <div class="price">
                          <p>${productData.price} руб</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="unit">
                         <button class="less">-</button>
                         <p class="unit-txt">${productData.quantity}</p>
                         <button class="more">+</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
            </div>




What is your expected result? how you want them to be?

Your problem is this: first thing for every <div class="product-card-container">
You didn't make a closing div tag.
Secondly, you must wrap all your products in a wrapping div whose design will look like this:
 #container {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 }

Here is the complete code (Make it full screen to see the results.):


.product-card-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .nft {
        user-select: none;
        width: 300px;
        margin: 2rem;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
        background-color: #282c34;
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(40, 44, 52, 1) 0%, rgba(17, 0, 32, .5) 100%);
        box-shadow: 0 7px 20px 5px #00000088;
        border-radius: .7rem;
        backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
        -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: .5s all;

        .wrapper li {
            margin: 10px 5px;
        }

        hr {
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #88888855;
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        ins {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .main {
            width: 90%;
            padding: 1rem;
            color: #c572e6;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;

            .tokenImage {
                border-radius: .5rem;
                max-width: 100%;
                height: 250px;
                object-fit: cover;
            }

            .description {
                min-height: 100px;
                max-height: 100px;
                margin: .5rem 0;
                color: #a89ec9;
            }

            .creator {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                margin-top: .2rem;
                margin-bottom: -.3rem;

                ins {
                    color: #a89ec9;
                    text-decoration: none;
                }

                .wrapper {
                    display: flex;
                    align-items: center;
                    border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
                    padding: .3rem;
                    margin: 0;
                    margin-right: .5rem;
                    border-radius: 100%;
                    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #000000aa;

                    img {
                        border-radius: 100%;
                        border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
                        width: 2rem;
                        height: 2rem;
                        object-fit: cover;
                        margin: 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ::before {
            position: fixed;
            content: "";
            box-shadow: 0 0 100px 40px #ffffff08;
            top: -10%;
            left: -100%;
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
            height: 60rem;
            transition: .7s all;
        }

        &:hover {
            border: 1px solid #ffffff44;
            box-shadow: 0 7px 50px 10px #000000aa;
            transform: scale(1.015);
            filter: brightness(1.3);

            ::before {
                filter: brightness(.5);
                top: -100%;
                left: 200%;
            }
        }
    }

    .bg {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

        h1 {
            font-size: 20rem;
            filter: opacity(0.5);
        }
    }

    #container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="product-card-container">
            <div class="nft">
                <div class='main'>
                    <img class='tokenImage' src="${productData.image}" alt="NFT" />
                    <h2 class="name-prod">${productData.name}</h2>
                    <div class='tokenInfo'>
                        <div class="price">
                            <p>${productData.price} руб</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="unit">
                        <button class="less">-</button>
                        <p class="unit-txt">${productData.quantity}</p>
                        <button class="more">+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-card-container">
            <div class="nft">
                <div class='main'>
                    <img class='tokenImage' src="${productData.image}" alt="NFT" />
                    <h2 class="name-prod">${productData.name}</h2>
                    <div class='tokenInfo'>
                        <div class="price">
                            <p>${productData.price} руб</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="unit">
                        <button class="less">-</button>
                        <p class="unit-txt">${productData.quantity}</p>
                        <button class="more">+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-card-container">
            <div class="nft">
                <div class='main'>
                    <img class='tokenImage' src="${productData.image}" alt="NFT" />
                    <h2 class="name-prod">${productData.name}</h2>
                    <div class='tokenInfo'>
                        <div class="price">
                            <p>${productData.price} руб</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="unit">
                        <button class="less">-</button>
                        <p class="unit-txt">${productData.quantity}</p>
                        <button class="more">+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-card-container">
            <div class="nft">
                <div class='main'>
                    <img class='tokenImage' src="${productData.image}" alt="NFT" />
                    <h2 class="name-prod">${productData.name}</h2>
                    <div class='tokenInfo'>
                        <div class="price">
                            <p>${productData.price} руб</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="unit">
                        <button class="less">-</button>
                        <p class="unit-txt">${productData.quantity}</p>
                        <button class="more">+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-card-container">
            <div class="nft">
                <div class='main'>
                    <img class='tokenImage' src="${productData.image}" alt="NFT" />
                    <h2 class="name-prod">${productData.name}</h2>
                    <div class='tokenInfo'>
                        <div class="price">
                            <p>${productData.price} руб</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="unit">
                        <button class="less">-</button>
                        <p class="unit-txt">${productData.quantity}</p>
                        <button class="more">+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-card-container">
            <div class="nft">
                <div class='main'>
                    <img class='tokenImage' src="${productData.image}" alt="NFT" />
                    <h2 class="name-prod">${productData.name}</h2>
                    <div class='tokenInfo'>
                        <div class="price">
                            <p>${productData.price} руб</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="unit">
                        <button class="less">-</button>
                        <p class="unit-txt">${productData.quantity}</p>
                        <button class="more">+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-card-container">
            <div class="nft">
                <div class='main'>
                    <img class='tokenImage' src="${productData.image}" alt="NFT" />
                    <h2 class="name-prod">${productData.name}</h2>
                    <div class='tokenInfo'>
                        <div class="price">
                            <p>${productData.price} руб</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="unit">
                        <button class="less">-</button>
                        <p class="unit-txt">${productData.quantity}</p>
                        <button class="more">+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>



